# Powercli script to join computer to the Domain

Tags: powershell, dns, invoke, powercli, powershell-cmdlet

I'm tring to run Powercli script from VM that have all the modules nedded.
The script should insert other VM to domain.

```
$ScriptText ="Add-Computer -DomainName foofoo.com -DomainCredential " + $DomainC +"  -OUPath 'OU=CACI,OU=Computers,OU=bla,OU=Regions,DC=bla,DC=com'" 
echo $Script
Invoke-VMScript -vm $VMName -GuestCredential $AdminC -ScriptText $ScriptText
```

all the variables inserted correctly.

runing 
`Add-Computer -DomainName foofoo.com -DomainCredential $DomainC -OUPath 'OU=CACI,OU=Computers,OU=bla,OU=Regions,DC=bla,DC=com'` 
 from the other vm poweshell console is running well and the output message `WARNING: The changes will take effect after you restart the computer ..`

$Script return:

`Add-Computer -DomainName foofoo.com -DomainCredential System.Net.NetworkCredential  -OUPath 'OU=CACI,OU=Computers,OU=bla,OU=Regions,DC=bla,DC=com'`

but after that this script stuck and I have no error or other output.

Any idea what is the reason for that ?

Comment: What happens when you run the script ` Add-Computer ...` on the VM directly?

Comment: I edit the answer - it's run well and the VM inserted to the domain. thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Add-Computer CMDlet takes a credential object for the domain credential parameter.  By trying to convert that to a string in your $scripttext variable - you're losing the credential type in the conversion.  You need to make a credential object inside your script text rather than passing in a variable containing the credential object. This adds some complexity because you generally want to pull a password from a secure vault.  The below examples shows how to include the password as a plain text - but this isn't really advised for obvious reasons.

```
$scripttext = @'
$user = "UserName"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "bar" -AsPlainText -Force
$DomainC = New-Object PSCredential $user, $password
Add-Computer -DomainName foofoo.com -DomainCredential $DomainC -OUPath 'OU=CACI,OU=Computers,OU=bla,OU=Regions,DC=bla,DC=com'
'@
Invoke-VMScript -vm $VMName -GuestCredential $AdminC -ScriptText $ScriptText
```